Parallel solution of several functions
I have a large and complex function with 5 variables f[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_] and three specific values for e, say e1, e2, e3. I substitute these values in f and treat them as three new functions, like this:
f1[a_, b_, c_, d_] = f[a, b, c, d, e1];
f2[a_, b_, c_, d_] = f[a, b, c, d, e2];
f3[a_, b_, c_, d_] = f[a, b, c, d, e3];

Next, I Solve the functions f1,f2,f3 with respect to b, and assign their solutions to new functions like this:
ff1[a_, c_, d_] = b /. Solve[f1[a, b, c, d] == 0, b][[1]]
ff2[a_, c_, d_] = b /. Solve[f2[a, b, c, d] == 0, b][[1]]
ff3[a_, c_, d_] = b /. Solve[f3[a, b, c, d] == 0, b][[1]]

It takes a long time to solve them one by one, so I want to do it simultaneously (in parallel) on different cores(kernels). Like solve ff1 on kernel 1, ff2 on kernel 2 etc. My PC have 64 GB RAM and 16 cores which allows me to start 16 local kernels, but by default only 1 used and its RAM reaches 7-8 GB after Solving them all. I find it very ineffective. I didn't find any good examples that can help me with this problem. Is it even possible? If yes then how to do it?

For an example, we define an array of equations:
eqns = Table[(x |-> Evaluate[Sin[i x^2 + x]])[x] == 0, {i, 3}];

Now we use "ParallelMap" to solve for the zeros of these functions:
ParallelMap[Solve[#, x] &, eqns]

This produces a list of lists that each contains the 4 possible solutions.
